# Connect Android app with WordPress site via json

Tags: android, json, wordpress

How to connect a WordPress site with an Android app via json results. Does it require plug-ins to be added in the site. If so what? And does each plug in have different way of retrieving json results? And when the site is in the developmental stage how would you test the json results. Please excuse me if the question is amateur. Any help would be useful. Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**How to connect Android app with Wordpress site**

This is very general question so I'll refer you to the best practice libraries to perform this task.
We'll use basic JSON REST API over Http ([guide](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/introducing-the-wp-rest-api--cms-24533)) to talk between our site and our mobile app.

On the Site side -
[Wordpress plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-rest-api/) to enable rest api from the site.([Guide with testing examples](https://www.sitepoint.com/wp-api/))

On the Android app side - 
[Retrofit](http://Retrofit) - Very good open source library to pass json over http in android.
([Guide](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Consuming-APIs-with-Retrofit))

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the REST API is included in wordpress in its 4.7 version. No plugins needed!!

[Post announcement](https://wordpress.org/news/2016/12/vaughan/)

[API Documentation](http://v2.wp-api.org/)